# Getting floating point exceptions when using specific registers

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I have a below code when executed i see Floating point exception

```
.section .data
var1:
        .int 20
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
        movl $var1, %edx
        movl (%edx), %eax
        movl $5, %ecx
        div %ecx
        movl %eax, %ebx
        movl $1, %eax
        int $0x80
```

when i execute the above code i get Floating point exception

```
../../bin/a49
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

But in the above code if i change the register storing the address of var1 from edx to ecx, It works as expected

```
.section .data
var1:
        .int 20
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
        movl $var1, %ecx
        movl (%ecx), %eax
        movl $5, %ecx
        div %ecx
        movl %eax, %ebx
        movl $1, %eax
        int $0x80
```

When i execute the above code i don't see the FPE.

```
$ ../../bin/a49
$ echo $?
4
```

I am unable to understand the above behaviour.

Comment: EDX is the upper half of the dividend for `div` so it faults when the quotient doesn't fit in EAX.

Comment: Also note that in a statically-linked Linux executable, all registers (except ESP) are zeroed before entry to `_start`.  So your 2nd version has `20` correctly zero-extended into EDX:EAX.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes for the explanation.